# Draw a tracing line with PointCloudRajawaliRenderer (Project Tango)

Tags: opengl-es, google-project-tango, rajawali

I am modifying the "java_point_cloud_example" program to plot a footprint of my past positions.

How can I draw a following line that traces my positions in OpenGL, which is similar to the "Odometry" app that Johnny used in his presentation?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvgPrZNp4So&t=12m29s

[image: following line]

Or is the source code of this "Odometry" app available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The odometry app is not open sourced.
2. [Drawing lines in open gles 2.0 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027455/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-line-using-opengl-es-android).
3. [Drawing lines in Rajawalli](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-18-Drawing-Lines) (the rendering library used in Tango java example)

Comment: How to write a text above 3d Line (tango)?

mLine = new Line3D(mPoints, 50, Color.YELLOW);
Material m = new Material();
m.setColor(Color.BLACK);
mLine.setMaterial(m);
getCurrentScene().addChild(mLine);